Reading and interpreting supply and demand curves
I have just been introduced to the topic of supply and demand curves in my mathematical modelling course. When we read the curve, we often say "an increase or decrease in the price results in so and so happening." My issue with this is that we tend to interpret the graph by analysing it in both directions (i.e., right to left and left to right), unlike the way we typically read the graph of a function, which is left to right. An example is when we look at rate of change or concavity.
Why is it that we can read the supply and demand curve in such a way since it has been graphed using functions? What am I missing?


What do you mean with "analysing it ... right to left"?

@VARulle if we want to look at how price changes with quantity decreasing, then we are looking at the graph from right to left instead of the typical way we look at graph which is left to right

It's true for every graph that if you study what happens if the value on the horizontal axis decreases you have to read it "right to left". The only unusual thing in this graph is that the dependent variable (quantity) is on the horizontal instead of the vertical axis, as it is the standard in mathematics. So it's reading "bottom to top" instead of "left to right" what one has to do.
